# laravel : php artisan not working

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I know there is bunch of answer out there and none of them solved my problem. I am giving a try again in 2016 may be some one can help.

```
php artisan make:migration createxxxtable
```

don't show any error and it don't create the file

neither of these function output anything too.

```
php artisan list
php artisan help migrate
```

Its not new project. I had been working on this project earlier and it was working fine. Created bunch of migration.

I tried deleting everying inside vendor and do `composer install` and `composer update`  still no luck.

I did tried command like dump-autoload , optimize , clear-compiled etc. too

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install a fresh copy of laravel and try php artisan there?

Comment: ok i am going to try that

Comment: @JilsonThomas Ok its working on fresh new project. What then ?

Comment: I suspect you need to move all your controllers, configs, composer.json, models, view to new project. I had to do this once. tried everything and didn't work anything out.

Comment: Yeah seems many people had this issue but no one got it solved ( mentioned how to solve it ). Thanks atleast you gave me a way how to work this out. Didn't thought of this before.

Comment: Should I provide this as answer?

Comment: I don't know. Its not exactly a right solution but do solve the problem. Ok then do post it. If no one able to give better answer by 24hrs. I will accept it.

Comment: before that, do you have all the subdirectories in the storage folder?

Comment: yeah i still have. What should i do with them ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas I found the cause. I posted the solution. May be u had this kind of thing too that time. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok found the solution. I don't know whats the reason. But it was because I was using `url()` helper in a *custom config file* i created in config folder.  The config file and value of url and others works fine all across the website but it just break artisan command. I don't know why.

Removing that `url()` helper from my custom config file solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you man! I would have NEVER figured that was the cause without you. Saved me a lot of time and stress.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when this issue arises it's due to an error in your code. Check for these coporates

1. Could be a typo in your .env file
2. Could be a syntax error in your .env
3. Entering in wrong configuration(syntax error) in your config folder

Answer (score 0):

can you please try php artisan does that open up the artisan commands?
If these doesn't show anything then check your path to project in console.

Comment: i did `php artisan` nothing show up.. i tried `ls` and i am in right folder seeing artisan file

Comment: BTW you seems to be new here. This kind of reply is more like comment. So may be next time you follow how Stackoverflow work :) No offence.